# Selenium WebDriver, изменение кода страницы перед выполнением теста.

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Есть некое поле `<input type="hidden" name="user_right_as_admin" value="0">`
Можно ли в автоматическом режиме изменить значение `value="0"`на `value="1"`и если да, то как?

Answer (score 0):

```
find("user_right_as_admin").value(1)
```

Какой вопрос, такой ответ.